# Call to undefined function is_home() or any conditional tags

Tags: plugin-development, functions, filters, hooks, actions

Currently I am coding in my own custom plugin. For some reason I can't use conditional tags inside my function. For example

```
 function check_home() {
    if(is_home()) {
       $my_val=1;
    } else {
     $my_val=2;
    }
    return $my_val;
  }
```

It's returning following error

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_home()**

I checked and I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393813/is-home-is-front-page-not-working) & it is working fine.

It saying to add this `add_action('wp', 'check_home');`

But now I want to get the value of function to variable. But it is showing error.

```
 add_action('wp', 'check_home');
 function check_home() {
    if(is_home()) {
       $my_val=1;
    } else {
     $my_val=2;
    }
    return $my_val;
  }
  
  $my_ver = check_home();
  echo $my_ver;
```

Then it showing following error.

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_home()**

Now how can i solve this error ? What i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a timing issue. This tries to call `is_home()` before that function exists.

```
$my_ver = check_home();
```

It works in the function called by `add_action` because then `is_home()` does exist because WP has fully loaded.

If you load php files in your plugin, then you can call `check_home` anytime in those files.

For example:

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
function ab_load_files() {
   require( MY_PLUGIN_PATH . '/ab-functions.php' );
}    
add_action( 'init', 'ab_load_files' );
```

Then this code will work if placed in ab-functions.php

```
$my_ver = check_home();
echo $my_ver;
```

Comment: Thank you . This seems to be more reasonable. I will try this. I wonder from where you are getting these informations.